# Getting hexagonal arrays of dots arranged in this spiral pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61382568/3904031) explain why I can't reliably get `int` type arrays. While there are some workarounds I have a hunch there's a better, cleaner or otherwise "less tricky" way to get these hexagonal arrays of dots arranged in this spiral pattern than the way I've done it by using several conditions.

Is my hunch correct?

**Note:** `hexit_60()` and `get_points()` are used in different ways in other places so I don't want to combine them.

**Context:** This is used in a simulation and plotting routine for points in reciprocal space of a hexagonal lattice as part of a diffraction calculator.

[image: hexagonal array of dots]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def hexit_60(n_max):
    pairs = []
    if n_max >= 0:
        pairs.append(np.zeros(2, dtype=int)[:, None])
    if n_max >= 1:  # https://stackoverflow.com/q/61382568/3904031 trap 0*[n] because casts to float
        seq = [1, 0, -1]
        p0  = np.hstack((seq, seq[::-1]))
        N   = len(p0)
        p1  = np.hstack((p0[N-2:], p0[:N-2]))
        pairs.append(np.stack((p0, p1), axis=0))
    for n in range(2, n_max+1):
        seq = np.arange(n, -n-1, -1, dtype=int)
        p0  = np.hstack((seq, (n-1)*[-n], seq[::-1], (n-1)*[n]))
        N   = len(p0)
        p1  = np.hstack((p0[N-2*n:], p0[:N-2*n]))
        pairs.append(np.stack((p0, p1), axis=0))
    if len(pairs) > 0:
        pairs = np.hstack(pairs)
    else:
        pairs = None
    return pairs

def get_points(a, n_max):
    vecs = a * np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5*np.sqrt(3)]])
    pairs = hexit_60(n_max = n_max)
    if isinstance(pairs, np.ndarray):
        points = (pairs[:, None]*vecs[..., None]).sum(axis=0)
    else:
        points = None
    return points

fig = plt.figure()
for i, n_max in enumerate([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i+1)
    # plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
    ax.set_title('n_max: ' + str(n_max))
    points = get_points(a=1.0, n_max=n_max)
    if isinstance(points, np.ndarray):
        x, y = points
        ax.scatter(x, y)
        ax.plot(x, y, '-k', linewidth=0.5)
    ax.set_xlim(-4.2, 4.2)
    ax.set_ylim(-4.2, 4.2)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## return early

For the special case, `n_max == -1`, you can return early

```
def hexit_60(n_max):
    if n_max == -1:
        return None
```

This allows you to simplify the loop a lot

## special case

the part before the `for`-loop can be included in the main loop by taking one of the other answers to your `int` question, and use casting.

## reverse

The reverse of `seq` is also the negative. If you extract the `(n-1)*[-n]` to another variable, you can make this a lot clearer.

## `np.roll`

`np.hstack((p0[N-2*n:], p0[:N-2*n]))` is equivalent to `np.roll(p0, 2 * n)`

## generator

You can make the `hexit_60` into a generator, even further simplifying it

```
def hexit_60_gen(n_max):
    if n_max == -1:
        return
    yield np.zeros(2, dtype=int)[:, None]
    for n in range(1, n_max + 1):
        seq = np.arange(-n, n + 1, dtype=int)
        middle = np.array((n - 1) * [-n], dtype=int)
        p0 = np.hstack((-seq, middle, seq, -middle,))
        p1 = np.roll(p0, 2 * n)
        yield np.vstack((p0, p1))
```

This code is a lot clearer to read to me.

It generates the same points:

```
all(
    np.array_equal(
        hexit_60(n_max), np.hstack(list(hexit_60_gen(n_max)))
    )
    for n_max in range(10)
)
```

## get_points

You need to adapt this slightly:

```
def get_points_gen(a, n_max):
    vecs = a * np.array([[1.0, 0.0], [0.5, 0.5 * np.sqrt(3)]])
    pairs = list(hexit_60_gen(n_max=n_max))
    if pairs:
        return (np.hstack(pairs)[:, None] * vecs[..., None]).sum(axis=0)
```

if `pairs` is empty, this returns `None` implicitly.

The one thing I would is replace `[0.5, 0.5 * np.sqrt(3)]` by

```
angle = np.pi / 3 # diagonal
[np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)]
```

So you don't have as many magic numbers in the code

## draw_hexagon

can be simplified with a slight reordering and a `continue`

```
def draw_hexagon():
    fig = plt.figure()
    for i, n_max in enumerate([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i+1)
        # plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
        ax.set_title('n_max: ' + str(n_max))
        points = get_points_gen(a=1.0, n_max=n_max)
        ax.set_xlim(-4.2, 4.2)
        ax.set_ylim(-4.2, 4.2)
        if points is None:
            continue
        x, y = points
        ax.scatter(x, y)
        ax.plot(x, y, '-k', linewidth=0.5)
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

This latest part can be made a bit cleaner, using the principles of clean architecture, but this is good enough, or a bit more parametrized, but this is good enough.

--

## alternative approach

Instead of the approach of the `hexit_60`, you can have a function to assemble the first side of the hexagon, and then apply rotations to this:

```
ANGLE = np.pi / 3
COS_ANGLE = np.cos(ANGLE)
SIN_ANGLE = np.sin(ANGLE)
ROTATION_MATRIX = [[COS_ANGLE, -SIN_ANGLE], [SIN_ANGLE, COS_ANGLE]]
```

Then to get one side, using `np.linspace` to do the interpolation:

```
def side_points(n):
    if n == 0:
        return np.array([[0], [0]])
    p0 = np.array([n, 0])
    p1 = n * np.array([COS_ANGLE, SIN_ANGLE])
    return np.linspace(p0, p1, n, endpoint=False).T
```

And then the rotations is a simple generator

```
def rotations(side):
    yield side
    if np.array_equal(side, np.array([[0], [0]])):
        return
    for _ in range(5):
        side = np.dot(ROTATION_MATRIX, side)
        yield side
```

Note that this can be easily adjusted to any regular polygon, by adjusting the angle, and passing in the appropriate cosinus, sinus and or rotation_matrix as function parameter instead of using the global

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(None)
def cos_angle(sides):
    return np.cos(2 * np.pi / sides)


@lru_cache(None)
def sin_angle(sides):
    return np.sin(2 * np.pi / sides)


@lru_cache(None)
def rotation_matrix(sides):
    return np.array(
        [
            [cos_angle(sides), -sin_angle(sides)],
            [sin_angle(sides), cos_angle(sides)],
        ]
    )


def side_points(n, sides=6):
    if n == 0:
        return np.array([[0], [0]])
    p0 = np.array([n, 0])
    p1 = n * np.array([cos_angle(sides), sin_angle(sides)])
    return np.linspace(p0, p1, n, endpoint=False).T


def rotations(side, sides=6):
    yield side
    if np.array_equal(side, np.array([[0], [0]])):
        return
    rot = rotation_matrix(sides)
    for _ in range(sides - 1):
        side = np.dot(rot, side)
        yield side


def points(n_max, sides=6):
    return np.hstack(
        list(
            itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                rotations(side_points(n, sides), sides)
                for n in range(n_max + 1)
            )
        )
    )
```

Then drawing the polygon is simply:

```
def draw_polygon(sides=6):
    fig = plt.figure()
    for i, n_max in enumerate([-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i + 1)
        # plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
        ax.set_title("n_max: " + str(n_max))
        ax.set_xlim(-4.2, 4.2)
        ax.set_ylim(-4.2, 4.2)
        if n_max < 0:
            continue
        all_points = points(n_max, sides=sides)
        ax.scatter(*all_points)
        ax.plot(*all_points, "-k", linewidth=0.5)
        ax.set_aspect("equal")
    return fig
```

> ```
> draw_polygon(7)
> ```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This will take me a bit of time to review but I can tell already it's very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Nice answer. You don't show the actual call to `draw_polygon` that was used to make the plots.  Are they supposed to be seven (7) sided polygons?

Comment: that is a 7-sided polygon indeed. I added the call in the code

Comment: Gee I can't keep up with the progress in your answer. :-) But the original post already solved my problem soI think in this case no need to hold out for further answers, this one's super, above, beyond etc.!